# Conditional formatting and exporting to excel using R

Tags: r, export-to-excel

```
color_pick <- function(column){
sapply(column,
     FUN = function(value) {
       if (value >= 90) {
         return("green")
       } else if (value > 80 && value < 90) {
         return("orange")
       } else if (value < 80) {
         return("red")
       }
     })
}
cf <- condformat(as.data.frame(d)) %>%
rule_fill_discrete(PERCENT,  expression = color_pick(PERCENT))
```

The output colours I am getting is red for value >90, blue for value <80 and green for value between 80 and 90. how to get correct colours in respective cells ?

```
 condformat2excel(
 cf,
 "RESULT_2021.xlsx",
 sheet_name = "18",
 overwrite_wb = FALSE,
 overwrite_sheet = TRUE)
```

Also when writing the output in excel the date time format is not in POSIXct but become numeric how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any data so I made my own. You're asking two questions which goes against site guidelines. I can solve your first one relating to colours but I suspect the second one is too much for the `condformat` package.

```
library(condformat)
library(lubridate)
    
df <- data.frame(PERCENT=c(10,80,81,90,91,95), Dates=ymd_hms(Sys.time()))
    
cf <-
    condformat(df) %>%
    rule_fill_discrete('PERCENT', expression=cut(df$PERCENT, breaks=c(0,80,90,100), include.lowest=T, labels=F), colours=c('1'='red', '2'='orange', '3'='green'))
    
condformat2excel(cf, 'df.xlsx')
```

The `cut` function works out what the colour should be and it's important to use the `colours` argument when calling the `rule_fill_discrete` function.

The resulting spreadsheet looks like this.

[image]

The date is a number but the best I can do is to manually format it to be a date.